# Echo image through PHP

Tags: php, base64

For an newsletter script I like to use an image to check if it is read or not. So we made an image like this in our script:

```
<img src="[url]/getEmailImage/test/">
```

When this url is triggered it registers that the mail is opened.

At the server side we use this meganism:

```
// register that the email is read
$this->modelOpslag->changeByToken($token,array('gelezen' => '1'));  

// download image and show is
$image = base_url().'external/afbeeldingen/pixel.jpg';
$info = getimagesize($image);   
header('Content-Type: '.$info['mime']);
echo file_get_contents($image);             
exit;
```

When i remove the PHP header function is shows something like this:

```
����JFIF``��rExifMM*JR(1Z``paint.net 4.0.5��
```

etc...

With the header my browser gives the error: the image cannot be displayed, because is contains errors.

What did I do wrong?

-- EDIT --

I've got no solutions for this specific problem, but i found an alternative in case someone like to use this meganism for their newsletter witch works:

```
$file = './external/afbeeldingen/pixel.jpg';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly.. you are trying to echo the image, using echo we cannot display the image..
Why don't you use...

```
<img src="<?php echo file_get_contents($image); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the email is build in HTML. So we cannot use PHP in it. When clicking in download images in the email client the url is requested and we register that the email is read. This works fine but on the place of this email it gives an image not found icon.

Answer (score 0):

you need different headers for image download and for showing image dynamically.  Also file encoding format of the php script can cause broken image data.